# How to use Jquery to find and display elements from an XML file loaded by a user from a locally held file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, domparser

I have the following code which loads a locally held xml file and displays an element using DOMPArser. Despite trying many solutions and as Im new to this I do not understand how to apply JQuery to perform operations finding and and displaying elements on an HTML form. Could someone be kind enough to show me how this is done. Once I know how to run Jqueries and display results I can then crack on. Any help would be much appreciated. I have seen examples using HTTPRequest to get file but I cannot do this must be local file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<input type="file" onchange="readfile(this)" >
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
    function readfile(fileinputobj){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
      
        //Using DOMParser to get XMLDocument
       var parser = new DOMParser(), xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(reader.result, "text/xml");
       document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title") 
      [0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
      document.getElementById("list").innerHTML =    x[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

   }
    reader.readAsText(fileinputobj.files[0]);   
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you add an xml example file ? Also, could you be more precise in what you're willing to accomplish (what should be displayed where) ?

Comment: I have been scouring the examples on

Comment: So may sticking point is I can load an xml file then to string via DomParser andI can do element search but I want to be able to run more specific searches via Jqueries and display the results e,,g in a text field to being with.

Comment: So you know how to find the xml element you want to display, and you want to create a text field containing that value in jquery ?

Comment: at the minute I only know how to load a local xml file into DOMPArser. I would like to know how to implement a JQuery  search on that loaded xml file and display in a text field please.

Answer (score 1):

To search specific elements in your loaded xml using jquery instead of javascript, you need to wrap the XML you parsed in a jquery object:

`var xmlWrapper = $(xmlDoc)`

Then you can use jquery methods (e.g. [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)) to get to the elements you need:

`var title = xmlWrapper.find("title").text();`

(if you need info on how to make more complex selectors than simply `"title"`, you can start by the [W3C CSS Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) and then if need be [Jquery specific selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/))

When you have found what you want to display, you have to put the content in a text field.

- If the textfield already exists, then you can retrieve it via its selector: `var textInput = $("your selector here")`
- If the textfield doesn't exist, you can create it via jquery like so: `var textInput = $('<input/>');` then set it as a text input: `textInput.attr("type", 'text');` and finally append the element wherever you want: `textInput.appendTo('body');`.

At this point, you have the element you want to display (`title` in my example) and the input (`textInput`) in which you want to put the element. Only remains to actually add the info in the input: `textInput.val(title);`

I created a jsfiddle so you can see the whole code in action: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9h8uvwa/)

Note: if you want to fully use jquery, you can also get rid of the [XML DOM Parser](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) and use [jQuery.parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) instead: `var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(reader.result);` but that's not mandatory, you can keep your `xmlDoc` as it is if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

That is just what I needed  now I can load my xml and display in a text field for now with the code below. THANK YOU soooo much I had spent many hours on this and was getting nowhere, your help has got me over this hurdle, I really appreciate the help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
   <input type="file" onchange="readfile(this)" >
   <output id="list"></output>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>

  <script>
    function readfile(fileinputobj){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          
        //Using DOMParser to get XMLDocument
        var parser = new DOMParser(), xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(reader.result, 
    "text/xml");
        
        
    
    var xmlWrapper = $(xmlDoc)
    var title = xmlWrapper.find("title").text();
    var textInput = $('<input/>');
    textInput.attr("type", 'text'); 
    textInput.appendTo('body');
    textInput.val(title);
   }
    reader.readAsText(fileinputobj.files[0]);   
   }
   </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: Glad to read that ! You may consider accepting my answer then :)